# Making a widget swipeable in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to make a collection of widgets inside a **FLoatLayout** that are swipeable and go up and down. Like a showcase or a gallery widget, however, I cannot seem to configure the swipe ability. I thought that maybe I could use the **Carousel** widget to achieve this which would be ultimately better since it has all the features and behaviors needed for a swiper but I could not figure out a way for the items to bleed into one another since that is the look I am going for. Is there a way I could bind swipe events to my floatlayout? My Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.animation import Animation

Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size
Builder.load_string('''
<Item@Button>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    font_size: 32
<Swiper>:
    Item:
        text: "Button 1"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": len(self.parent.children) * .5}
        on_release: root.change_pos(self)
    Item:
        text: "Button 2"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": (len(self.parent.children) - 1) * .5}
        on_release: root.change_pos(self)
    Item:
        text: "Button 3"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": (len(self.parent.children) - 2) * .5}
        on_release: root.change_pos(self)
    Item:
        text: "Button 4"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": (len(self.parent.children) - 3) * .5}
        on_release: root.change_pos(self)
    Item:
        text: "Button 5"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": (len(self.parent.children) - 4) * .5}
        on_release: root.change_pos(self)
    Item:
        text: "Button 6"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": (len(self.parent.children) - 5) * .5}
        on_release: root.change_pos(self)
''')


class Swiper(FloatLayout):
    focused_index = 0
    def change_pos(self, instance):
        instance_index = self.children.index(instance)
        if instance_index < self.focused_index:
            for item in self.children:
                Animation(pos_hint={"center_y": item.pos_hint["center_y"]+.5}).start(item)
        elif instance_index > self.focused_index:
            for item in self.children:
                Animation(pos_hint={"center_y": item.pos_hint["center_y"]-.5}).start(item)
        else:
            print("item already has focus")
        self.focused_index = instance_index


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Swiper()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Carousel` like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size

kv = Builder.load_string('''
<Item@Button>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    font_size: 32
Carousel:
    direction: 'right'
    Item:
        text: "Button 1"
    Item:
        text: "Button 2"
    Item:
        text: "Button 3"
    Item:
        text: "Button 4"
    Item:
        text: "Button 5"
    Item:
        text: "Button 6"
''')


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Another possibility is to use a `GridLayout` inside a `ScrollView`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.minimum_width, Window.minimum_height = Window.size

kv = Builder.load_string('''
<Item@Button>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size[0] + 100, self.texture_size[1] + 100
    font_size: 32
ScrollView:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: b1.height
            Item:
                id: b1
                text: "Button 1"
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: b2.height
            Item:
                id: b2
                text: "Button 2"
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: b3.height
            Item:
                id: b3
                text: "Button 3"
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: b4.height
            Item:
                id: b4
                text: "Button 4"
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: b5.height
            Item:
                id: b5
                text: "Button 5"
        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: b6.height
            Item:
                id: b6
                text: "Button 6"
''')


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: I would like for the items to bleed into one another like how I made it with my FloatLayout, how do I achieve this with carousel?

Comment: `Carousel` only shows one `Item` at a time. Perhaps what you want is a `GridLayout` with just one column.

Comment: How exactly can I achieve with GridLayout? It does not seem feasible because I want to animate it as well. Can you demonstrate?

Answer (score -1):

I think this webiste has your answer

[https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.swipetodelete#:~:text=SwipeToDelete%20widget%20is%20built%20on,commit%20adds%20some%20new%20features](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.swipetodelete#:%7E:text=SwipeToDelete%20widget%20is%20built%20on,commit%20adds%20some%20new%20features).

***SwipeBehaviour Properties***

swipe_distance - Distance to move before swiping. NumericProperty(20)

swipe_timeout - Timeout allowed to trigger swipe_distance in milliseconds. NumericProperty(55)

swipe_rect_x - X position of the axis aligned bounding rectangle where swiping is allowed. NumericProperty(0)

swipe_rect_y - Y position of the axis aligned bounding rectangle where swiping is allowed. NumericProperty(0)

swipe_rect_width - Width of the axis aligned bounding rectangle where swiping is allowed. NumericProperty(100)

swipe_rect_height - Height of the axis aligned bounding rectangle where swiping is allowed. NumericProperty(100)

swipe_rectangle - Position and size of the axis aligned bounding rectangle where swiping is allowed. ReferenceListProperty(swipe_rect_x, swipe_rect_y, swipe_rect_width, swipe_rect_height)

remove_from_left - User has the choice to remove the widget from the left or not.

remove_from_right - User has the choice to remove the widget from the right or not.

animation_type - For different animation while returning back.

animation_duration - Duration of animation

right_percentage - Decide the limit to delete when user swipes to the right side.

left_percentage - Decide the limit to delete when user swipes to left side.

move_to - To move widgets

opacity_reduction_rate - Change the way at which opacity reduces.